# Link error dependent on for loop length

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a shader program with a for loop in the geometry shader. The program links (and operates) fine when the for loop length is small enough. If I increase the length then I get a link error (with empty log). The shaders compile fine in both cases. Here is the geometry shader code (with everything I thought relevant):

```
#version 330
layout (points) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 256) out;
...
void main()
{
    ...
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 22 ; ++i) // <-- Works with 22, not with 23.
    {
        ...
        EmitVertex();
        ...
        EmitVertex();
        ...
        EmitVertex();
        ...
        EmitVertex();

        EndPrimitive();
    }
}
```

The specs state: "non-terminating loops are allowed. The consequences of very long or non-terminating loops are platform dependent." Could this be a platform dependent situation (GeForce GT 640)? As the shader code evolved, the max length of the for loop changed (more code -> smaller max), leading me to suspect it has something to do with loop unrolling. Can anyone give me any more info on this issue? (Let me know if you need more code/description.)

Comment: Make sure you are not exceeding `GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS`. The spec (GL 4.5) guarantees a minimum of 1024 for this limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason for failure to link programs containing geometry shaders as the `GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS` limit. Section 11.3.4.5 "Geometry Shader Outputs" of the [OpenGL 4.5 core profile specifiaction](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf) states (my emphasis):

> There are two implementation-dependent limits on the value of `GEOMETRY_VERTICES_OUT`; it may not exceed the value of `MAX_GEOMETRY_OUTPUT_VERTICES`, and the product of the total number of vertices and the sum of all
>   components of all active output variables may not exceed the value of `MAX_GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS`. **`LinkProgram` will fail if it determines
>   that the total component limit would be violated.**

The GL guarantees that this toal component limit is at least 1024.

You did not paste the full code of your shaders, so that it is unclear how many components per vertex you are using, but it might be a reason for a link failure.

> If I increase the length then I get a link error (with empty log).

The spec does not require any linker or compiler messages at all. However, Nvidia usually provides quite good log messages. If you can reproduce the "link failure without log message" scenario in the most current driver version, it might be worth filing a bug report.

Comment: @thethuthinnang: You were right, I accidently quoted the wrong paragraph. I fixed my answer.